# What is the minimum spacing between memory slots on the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, memory-card, dimensions

I'm planning to purchase the motherboard [GIGABYTE G1.Sniper B5](http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/gigabyte-g1sniper-b5-intel-b85-soket-1150-ddr3-1600mhz-hdmi-anakart.html) along with a pair of pair of (2 x (2 x Sticks) = 4 Sticks) DDR3 memory [CMY16GX3M2A1600C9](http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-pro-series-16gb-2-x-8gb-ddr3-dram-1600mhz-c9-memory-kit-cmy16gx3m2a1600c9). I found the dimensions of the memory stick [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D2LGRPG). It is said that each stick has 0.4"=10,16mm thickness. Unfortunately, I couldn't find memory slot dimensions in the [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/mb_manual_g1.sniper-b5_e.pdf).

I would like to know if the space between memory slots is standard in all motherboards, what is the minimum spacing for the worst case, and how do I make sure if these 10.16mm memory sticks would fit in this motherboard's slots or not.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this to be standard, best to contact the memory company and ask about comparability with the motherboard or vice versa

Comment: The heat spreader can be removed if it's a problem though